# Multiple bridged mqtt brokers to one central hub broker?

Tags: mqtt, bridge, broker

I have 100 remote rpi's each with their own local mqtt broker and various connected sensors (clients), operating offline 75% of the time.  I would like to have a central mqtt broker with bridges to all of the rpi local brokers.  Is this topology possible? When the rpi's go online can they sync their messages to the central broker?

Comment: Sensors are connected via bluetooth? Are all the Rasp's connected through LAN or wifi? Central broker is cloud server?

Comment: Sensors are connected by local lan and wifi to raspberry pi.  Raspberry pi connects to internet with cell every 30 minutes

Comment: If the data transferred is not too much, let's say 1 msg in few minutes, you can save that data locally onto the rasp after reading it. Have a periodic service on rasp, which runs every 30 min, a)connect to the internet, b) read the data stored on local rasp, c) send that data to the central server. Python scripts would be most easy.

Answer (score 0):

Verified this topology works with 3 brokers, 1 as central and the other two bridging! Nothing like trial and error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).